# Capacitive Power Supply Torch

Tags: power-supply, basic, capacitive, transformerless

I'm an amateur at electronics circuitry and concepts. I have designed a simple capacitive power supply using few web images and brief lessons. I understand that this type of transformerless power supply is highly dangerous. So i will take the utmost care while working with it.

[image]

The motive of the circuit is to charge a 4-4.2v battery (mAh capacity unknown) to operate a single 1 watt white LED when needed (basically a simple cheap flashlight circuit).

I tried to simulate the circuit in Falstad circuit simulator but it isn't the easiest and doesn't render at times( or renders different values at different times )

I have few questions, some of which might seem to be very simple(noobish) but please bare with me. Any kind of knowledge will be much appreciated.

Questions
1. If the mains are disconnected and the SWITCH OFF, can the battery discharge through resistor R3 then capacitor C2 through the 1n4007 Bridge rectifier and back to the negative terminal of the battery?

2. What effect does the values of resistors R1, R2 have on the overall circuit in terms of current and voltage output at capacitor C2?
3. Still need to calculate values for resistor R3, R4
4. Suggest any circuit/component modifications with basic electronic components along with some explanation or information.
5. Recommend an extensive circuit simulator with pcb design.

Thank you

Comment: this will overcharge and kill your battery. Use a proprietary charger IC.

Comment: @Neil_UK i wish to build my own circuit to learn electronics practically. Also i don't intend to spend too much money on this. The battery is a cheap Chinese generic battery.

Comment: No, please do not try this. You need to use a proper battery charger circuit. It doesn't matter how cheap the battery is, your hospital bills will be very expensive.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson then can you suggest a circuit or design that can charge a battery but with a capacitive power supply design?

Comment: Using a capacitive supply directly off the mains can be very dangerous, and it doesn't sound like you really have the required background knowledge. You should start by using a common 5V USB phone charger. There are lots of battery charger circuits, a search engine is your friend.

Comment: This cct is too primitive  7mA (limited by C1 film) , no cutoff, no OVP,  http://tinyurl.com/y4nd6wg7  C2 is redundant

Comment: I agree, a much more practical solution would be to use the 5v/100mA available from a USB port to charge a battery. You could try a LM317 with output at 4.1v through a suitable current-limiting resistor to a 4.2v battery. Then just plug it in overnight (or indefinitely) and should not have to worry about over-charging the battery. Easy, cheap, much safer.

Comment: IF the battery is LiIon then this circuit will destroy it. LiIon MUST be limited to a maximum of 4.2V  AND at 4.2V the charge current MUST be terminated when current falls to a designed low value. You CAN use this method if Vbattery is NEVER EVER above say 4.0V. | If the battery is 3 x NimH then Vmax needs to be about 1.4V/cell. 4.2V is good. 4.7V may be BUT a 4.7V zener is not sharp enough.  | What country are you in. Chinese source TP4056 charger modules cost under $US1 and are available in most countries. eg there are sellers in Pakistan.

Comment: Be aware that ALL parts of this circuit MUST be regarded as being at mains 240 VAC at all times. - as sooner or later even the N connected side may be.